# C++ Reinforcement learning and smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, reinforcement-learning

I am doing my Masters project on robotic's sensorimotor online learning using reinforcement learning methods (Q,sarsa,TD(λ),Actor-Critic,R,etc). I am currently designing the framework on which both higher level reinforcement learning and lower level robot API control will be using.

Since the states are robot sensor dependant and may (will) increase exponentially, I will be allocating them on the heap. Since this can create alot of problems, bugs, etc, and since parallelization (i.e. threading) is an aspect of reinforcement learning I want to explore, I am not yet sure of what kind of smart pointers to use.

Designing my own template/class for a smart pointer will take time and debugging, which I do not have. So, I am wondering, should I use STL's `auto_ptr`? I see they have issues being used in vectors. Should I use `boost::shared_ptr`? The states will have to be shared among many classes and algorithms. Or should I use `boost::ptr_vector`? Since the states will reside in a task container class in a vector, would this be sufficient? The states will have to be shared, copyable, referencable, serializable, non constant, thread-safe and will not be deleted. Also, memory space and computation time are important.

What do you recommend as the best smart ptr implementation for such a task ?

Thank you!

---

It seems like I will have to try using boost::ptr_vector with class State, and if this proves unefficient, then use std::vector < std::unique_ptr > and enable 0X.
Thank you all for your answers and suggestions !

Comment: No I do not, but I would consider using it, I'm using gcc 4.5 and I know it can be enabled, but has certain limitations. What's the advantage of 0X with respect to this issue ?

Comment: You could use `unique_ptr`, which is reasonably light-weight (lighter than `shared_ptr`). And since it's move-constructible, you can even use it in `std::vector`, I believe.

Comment: Thank you, I will seriously consider it, but since I am unaware on how enabling 0X might the entire project, I am a bit skeptic.

Comment: That's the least of the worries: Add `-std=c++0x` to your command line!

Comment: What are the advantages of using an std::vector<std::unique_ptr> over a boost::ptr_vector of raw pointers ?

Comment: I don't know the boost pointer container very well. The standard version obviously has the advantage of being ... well, in the standard. Whether there are performance differences I do not know.

Comment: I don't see where pointers come into play here. Normally, the state space would be a single fixed-size array allocated on the heap. It could be managed with a simple `vector`.

Answer (score 4):

Single-ownership pointers are the harder to misuse, modulo the design of `std::auto_ptr`. You could consider using `boost::scoped_ptr`, which is safer yet (it can't transfer ownership though and can't be returned from a function). When it comes to containers, you *could* use a pointer container, but it's also fine to use e.g. `std::vector` without smart pointers if the types involved are not used polymorphically.

Shared ownership should remain an exceptional case; don't overuse `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
If a pointer can't be returned from a function, well thats a problem. I do not care about transfering ownership. The types will be used polymorphically, at least some of them, so using std::vector is one of my problems.

Comment: @Alex `std::auto_ptr` is still an option. `const std::auto_ptr` also prevents accidental transfers of ownership.

Comment: I've read on the net that std::auto_ptr cannot be used in vectors, which is a big issue.

Comment: @Alex Do not use `std::auto_ptr` with standard containers. Use the Boost pointer containers for polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: Thank you that seems like a very good idea. I might actually use std::auto_ptr in a boost::ptr_vector

Comment: `auto_ptr` was the C++98-way of implementing transfer semantics without language support, and it's a spectacular hack. As a result, you cannot use it in containers, which in C++98 require element types to obey copy semantics. In C++0x, the `unique_ptr` is the correct way of doing what `auto_ptr` was trying to do.

Comment: @Alex Do not use a `boost::ptr_vector<std::auto_ptr<T> >` (or a `boost::ptr_vector<T*>`); use a `boost::ptr_vector<T>`. Check the documentation. (And `boost::ptr_vector<T>` is designed to interface with `std::auto_ptr<T>`.)

Answer (score 1):

Other suggestions missed one. `boost::intrusive_ptr` performs better than `shared_ptr` because it doesn't need a second allocation to hold the reference count. The downside of `intrusive_ptr` is a tiny bit of extra bookkeeping and no ability to use `weak_ptr`.

Comment: How tiny are we talking about ?

Comment: @Alex: You'd want to read the Boost documentation on it, but you need to provide a reference count field and functions to increment and decrement it.

Comment: yes I just read the documentation. I do not see however why it would be better than a shared_ptr which seems like my best bet for now.

Comment: @Alex: The shared_ptr reference is stored in a separate block of memory which causes another indirect pointer lookup and a second cache line bounce. intrusive_ptr also gives you direct insight into the reference count if you want to view it for yourself. It's just another option, not super important.

Answer (score 1):

I never found a smart ptr class that I liked when I was doing c++.  I wrote my own in the end.

It had a cache feature for speed so it you kept allocating and freeing memory it could just hang on to the memory it had and reuse it.  Also it had no default constructor so you had to pass it to functions/methods by reference else the compiler would show an error, this was so it would not create a temp copy of memory especially when dealing with large image files.

It would not take too long to write your own code and you can add your own bounds checking code to it as well.

Comment: Does your class have atomic reference count updates so it can be used in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: I never needed to write multi-threaded code at the time.  However if the code is used between critical-sections it should work?

Comment: Assuming I go down this road, what would I have to include besides a destructor, an atomic reference and a lock ?

Comment: Have a look at how `std::shared_ptr` is implemented :-) It's a surprising amount of bookkeeping code. `std::unique_ptr` should be a lot simpler, and thanks to move semantics it's also quite usable.

Comment: If you decide to write your own you need to override various operators to get it to work.  The locks you can use critical-sections or spin-locks.  It would also be a good idea to write it as template for future use.  However only you can decide if you have the time etc.

Comment: ...and never try to write your own before you have profiled and determined that the smart pointer class was the bottleneck!